# backbone model adding attributes programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to add attributes to a model, on the fly, like this:

```
var fieldName = e.currentTarget.name;
var model = this.collection.images.get("2");
model.set({fieldName: e.currentTarget.value});
```

So, as a user types in a given textbox, this code will be called.  The field name is a data attribute for a textbox that corresponds to the model attribute name.  The problem is that when this code runs, instead of inserting the given data into the correct attribute, it creates a new one called "fieldName".  For example, if e.currentTarget.Name = "test", I would expect that the model attribute called "test" would be set to a given value, not the literal "fieldName".  Is there anyway to use the passed value and not the literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax instead:

model.set(fieldName, e.currentTarget.value);